# Particle effect to mesh - Strange issue

Tags: mesh, particles

I am trying to convert a particle system using an object into a mesh, but am running into some issues.  When I hit convert under the modifiers tab, it adds the same object to all of the objects in the particle system.

It looks like I want it to with the parent and the objects coming from it before I hit convert, but when I do it adds the particle system to each object in the original system.

To make it more clear, I have a half UV sphere as the parent and a branch object that I made as the particle.  When I hit convert it adds branches to each branch particle.

Please help ):